# Error when making functions in my Python in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, eval

I have made a code. It works like we are running the original python. It uses `eval` and `exec`. When I try to make a function or any `if` statement in it ,it don't works. Here is the code:

```
print("Python\n")
while True:
    command =input(">>> ")
    if command == "quit()":break
    try:
        try:
            eval(command)
        except:
            exec(command)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Exception: "+str(err))
```

Running:

```
Python

>>> a = input("Enter your name: ")
Enter your name: abc
>>> print(a)
abc
>>> if True:
Exception: unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)
>>> if True:print(a);if a == "abc":print("Great Abc")
Exception: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
>>>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear and more over please mention the relation between the two code snapshots you have posted

Comment: `if True:` fails because something needs to come after the `:`. You can put `pass` there.

Comment: Why are you trying to mimic the REPL behavior?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried to press enter to type my code within it.

Comment: @mmmmmmmm `eval` can't know that. You can try `(if True` and then press enter, but I doubt it will work. Again, *why* are you trying to reinvent REPL?

Comment: @NaseerMohammad, The second code portion is the output of my code.

Comment: @DeepSpace That is the reason I used a second `try` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only processing one line at a time the python interpreter throws an error if you only write `if True:`. In the normal interpreter this would trigger a multi-line edit and only start executing when you make an empty line.

If you on the other hand put something after the if-statement it would work (e.g.`if True: print("true")`) But you cannot chain if-statements after one another like you try to do. You can however chain normal statements like `if True:print("first line");print("second line")`.

The same problem goes for functions. They need to have a statement following the definition before the can be interpreted and normally you would be allowed to type that definition before the function gets read.

You could change your code to allow for this behaviour so that if a line ends with `:` you should continue to read the input and only execute it after an empty line has been given as input.

Comment: @mmmmmmmm which example do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Eval fuction evalutes one line code, if statement demands minimal 2 lines(with indentation). Try lambda expression

```
lambda x: True if a == True else False
```

Comment: Not completely true. A if statement can have a statement follow on the same line. See my answer for more detail or try it out for yourself.