# Interact with python REPL from python script

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, read-eval-print-loop

I want to find (or make) a python script that reads a different python script line by line and prints the commands executed and the output right there after.

Suppose you have a python script, `testfile.py` as such:

```
print("Hello world")

for i in range(3):
    print(f"i is: {i}")
```

Now, I want a different python script that parses the `testfile.py` and outputs the following:

```
print("Hello world")
## Hello world
for i in range(3):
    print(f"i is: {i}")
## i is: 0
## i is: 1
## i is: 2
```

Any suggestions on existing software or new code on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated!

---

## Attempts / concept code:

#### Running `ipython` from python:

One of the first thoughts were to run ipython from python using `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
import re
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args=["ipython", "-i"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    # Delimiter to know when to stop reading
    OUTPUT_DELIMITER = ":::EOL:::"
    # Variable to contain the entire interaction:
    output_string = ""
    # Open testfile.py
    with open("testfile.py") as file_:
        for line in file_:
            # Read command
            cmd = line.rstrip()
            # Add the command to the output string
            output_string += cmd + "\n"
            proc.stdin.write(f"{cmd}\n")
            # Print the delimiter so we know when to end:
            proc.stdin.write('print("{}")\n'.format(OUTPUT_DELIMITER))
            proc.stdin.flush()
            # Start reading output from ipython
            while True:
                thisoutput = proc.stdout.readline()
                thisoutput = thisoutput.rstrip()
                # Now check if it's the delimiter
                if thisoutput.find(OUTPUT_DELIMITER) >= 0:
                    break
                output_string += thisoutput + "\n"

except Exception as e:
    proc.stdout.close()
    proc.stdin.close()
    raise
proc.stdout.close()
proc.stdin.close()
print("-" * 4 + "START OUTPUT" + "-" * 4)
print(output_string)
print("-" * 4 + "END OUTPUT" + "-" * 4)
```

In this approach, the problem becomes indented blocks, like the `for` loop.
Ideally something like this would work using just plain `python` (and not `ipython`).

Comment: Pretty much related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130639/error-when-making-functions-in-my-python-in-python#comment91211783_52130639

Comment: Why? What is the end goal? What benefit will this REPL/interpreter-mimicking-script have?

Comment: @DeepSpace The end goal is nicely typesetting python scripts. This would be the first step.

Comment: I figured it out by using the python `[code.InteractiveConsole.interact](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole.interact)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`code.InteractiveConsole.interact`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole.interact) does exactly what is asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not *exactly* what you wanted, but it's close. `trace` module does something very similar.

`so.py:`

```py
print("Hello world")
for i in range(3):
    print(f"i is: {i}")
```

```
python -m trace --trace so.py

 --- modulename: so, funcname: <module>
so.py(1): print("Hello world")
Hello world
so.py(3): for i in range(3):
so.py(4):     print(f"i is: {i}")
i is: 0
so.py(3): for i in range(3):
so.py(4):     print(f"i is: {i}")
i is: 1
so.py(3): for i in range(3):
so.py(4):     print(f"i is: {i}")
i is: 2
so.py(3): for i in range(3):
```